# What is the return type of the calculate method from the 'fast-crc32c' module?

Tags: typescript, crc32

I'm working with the `fast-crc32c` module ([github link](https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-crc32c)).

Looking at the [main exported function](https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-crc32c/blob/master/loader.js), its hard for me to figure out what the type of the result is.

For eg. I've had a look at one of the other files [here](https://github.com/ashi009/node-fast-crc32c/blob/master/impls/js_crc32c.js) and it seems like the return type should be a number (mostly because it uses [unassigned right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift).

I only understand cyclic redundancy check at a high level, hence my question to ask what the return type for the `calculate` method is.

Comment: `const crc32 = require(impl);` <- herer `crc32` is an object with one property `calculate` that is a function.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, do you know what the return type for the calculate function is? Sorry if my question wasn't clear

Comment: @nkhil it's `number`